# NoClassDefFoundError Error when trying to create new ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson, noclassdeffounderror

I'm new to Java and am trying to use Jackson to parse some JSON data.  However, I can't get past the creation of the object mapper.  In my code, I have:

```
`import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

... //other code
    `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  //this is line 46 that you see in the error below

Errors:

```
Sep 17, 2013 1:03:59 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at adtrax.rrh.BrandResource.createBrand(BrandResource.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:175)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:167)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:115)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:115)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:67)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:709)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:667)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:658)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:324)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:425)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:604)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 35 more
```

I have the jackson jars in my build path and checked in Order and Export.

Well, I don't have the reputation points to be allowed to include the image.  I have jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar, jackson-core-2.2.3.jar and jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar.

I think the issue is something simple, but I just can't see it.  Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like it's not a problem with Jackson but with the class path... Have you tried a full deploy?

Comment: Can you verify that these jars are included in `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: Mena - I am just running this in Eclipse and using SoapUI to call it.  This is part of a REST service that we are creating, and I am just trying to get it to work locally at first.

Comment: Mabbas - The jars are in a build repository along with all the other jars that we use and reference.  I can verify that they are there, are in the build path, and are checked in Order and Export.  Please forgive me if I'm not answering your question right.  I have a lot to learn with Java/Eclipse/Spring, etc.

Comment: The problem was that I did not realize that I had to also add things to my deployment assembly in addition to the build path.  This is my first ever Java service.  Thanks for the replies!